# yum + pre-existing rpmdb problem + yum complain about packages that already installed

Tags: rhel, python, yum, rpm, pip

we are trying to install the following rpm without success on rhel 7.2 server

```
 uname -r
3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64



yum install  python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
.
.
.
--> Processing Dependency: python-cffi >= 1.4.1 for package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-idna >= 2.0 for package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-pyasn1 >= 0.1.8 for package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) for package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python-ipaddress for package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64 (/python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: python-ipaddress
Error: Package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64 (/python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64 (/python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: python-cffi >= 1.4.1
           Available: python-cffi-0.8.6-2.el7.x86_64 (local)
               python-cffi = 0.8.6-2.el7
Error: Package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64 (/python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: python-pyasn1 >= 0.1.8
           Available: python-pyasn1-0.1.6-2.el7.noarch (local)
               python-pyasn1 = 0.1.6-2.el7
Error: Package: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64 (/python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: python-idna >= 2.0
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts containerd: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts runc: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
```

since we get `pre-existing rpmdb problem(s)`

we performed the follwing

```
package-cleanup --dupes
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

but the problem still remained

also what we found that the python packages that yum  Requires  are actually installed

example

```
pip list | grep idna
idna                               2.10

pip list | grep  pyasn1
pyasn1                             0.1.9
```

so we not understand why yum complained when python packages are already installed with the right version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using `pip` as well as `yum` to install packages. The packages installed by `pip` would not be visible to `yum`, which would be the reason why your installation is failing.

This article on opensource.com explains the concerns well: [Managing Python packages the right way](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/managing-python-packages). I will summarize the key information here.

When you install a package globally using `pip` (with `sudo pip install`), you install the package to a system-level location normally controlled by the OS package manager. However, the package manager is unaware of the package, which makes the installation inconsistent with the database of installed packages. In extreme cases, this can cause problems with system-level applications that rely on Python (such as `yum` itself).

In general, when installing a Python module globally, you should prefer the system's native package manager. These packages are tested with the specific version of the OS, so they should be more reliable.

If you really want to use `pip` to install a package, using virtual environments is recommended. With `virtualenv`, you get a local installation that you can modify as you see fit. You can install any package that you require, without risking the integrity of the system as a whole.

As always, there are trade-offs between both approaches. Evaluate them carefully before you proceed.

---

In your specific case, you may be able to proceed by removing the module with `pip`, and then reinstalling it via `yum`. I cannot guarantee that this would work, so use caution and test the approach first.

Regarding the actual package, I was able to find [a listing for CentOS 7](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=python-idna). On RHEL, you might need the Software Collections repository to get this package. Once again, ensure that you actually have the RPM package available over some channel before you decide to proceed with this route.